# Pushing Element to the top of an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
  0 =  Stat.clicks
  1 =  Stat.currency
  2 =  Stat.conversions
  3 =  Stat.payout
  4 =  Stat.ltr
```

Now if i want to push the element `Offer.name` ontop of this array without deleting `Stat.clicks` which is index 0 how would i do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: pedantic-semantics: An array is, essentially, a List, when you say the _top_, you're referring to the _last_ element. You mean the _bottom_ element (at index 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do:

```
array_unshift($array, 'Offer.name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) which will prepend the new element to the first index of the array.

Example:

```
$my_array = array("Stat.Clicks", "Stat.currency", "Stat.conversions", "Stat.payout", "Stat.ltr");

array_unshift($my_array, "Offer.name");
```

`$my_array` after `array_unshift` becomes:

```
 0 =  Offer.name
 1 =  Stat.clicks
 2 =  Stat.currency
 3 =  Stat.conversions
 4 =  Stat.payout
 5 =  Stat.ltr
```